# how call method without return-type in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, methods

i like to call a method without return-type in linq or in extension methods in linq?
Here my class i have situation line this

```
Class A
{
   int i;
   public int K
   {
     get { return i; }
     set { i = value; }
   }
   public void calculate(int z)
   {
     this.k=z;
   }
}
```

i like to do like this

```
List<A> sam = new List<A>();
//add elements to this list
var c = sam.Select( s => s.calculate(4) );
```

this sample only , i like to do like this for my purpose.

Comment: How to call a method without return type, LINQ or not: just call it! We need more info. Maybe if you show us some code explaining exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Why would you want to? LINQ is about *computing results*. void returning methods usually do not compute a result. Explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: The Q in LINQ stands for Query, I'm pretty sure it's meant to be for getting results as Eric says.

Comment: OK, suppose that worked. What would you do with "c"?  Remember, the result of a query expression is *the query*, not *the results of the query*. You'd have a query that represents calling a void method stored in variable c. What would you then do with it?

Comment: Anyone who doesn't understand why this is wanted should not be designing programming languages. Look at Scala's foreach ... it's just a "select" (an idiotic name for "map") that executes its lambda for its side effect and doesn't return a result.

Comment: You should never use a lambda with side effects in a LINQ query. To answer your question, you should use a `foreach` loop. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430033/sending-items-in-a-linq-sequence-to-a-method-that-returns-void).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean that you want to iterate a sequence ([IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)) and invoke code for it, you can inplement an extension method with an action, that is invoked for each item in the sequence, e.g.:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<T> list, System.Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T item in list)
        action(item);
}
```

This makes sense if you want to invoke small logic (one line) without implementing a foreach() block:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void DoSomethingInOneLine()
    {
        // do something
    }
}

public static void Test(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyClass> list)
{
    list.ForEach(item => item.DoSomethingInOneLine());
}
```

Comment: The problem is this will immediately iterate the sequence - it doesn't allow you to add a lazily-evaluated step to the Linq sequence list.

Answer (score 11):

You should use [`List<T>.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) here.

```
sam.ForEach(s => s.calculate(somenumber));
```

I think you use `.Select` in your question because you want to get the results(all the instances of A after calling `calculate`). You can get them directly by the variable `sam`. `ForEach` modifies each elements of sam, and the "changes" are applied to the list itself.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need the result, you can fill the result with a random value (e.g. `false`).

```
var c = sam.Select( s => {s.calculate(4); return false;} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this often:

Generic approach:

```
from item in sequence

// wrapping statements with lambda
let @void = new Func<bool>(() => {
   // whatever you like..
   return true;
})()

select item
```

If you want to do property assignment (bonus: example how to work with HTTP client :-):

```
..
// inside fluent LINQ query
let client = new HttpClient()

// initialise property and discard result
let @discard = client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new  AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("user:pass")))

// now work with initialised client according to your logic..
select client.GetAsync("url").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue. I sometimes find I prefer the declerative syntax of LINQ...

this was my call

```
// wont compile:
from ticket in actualTickets
group ticket by ticket.ID into ticketGroup
select AddToBasket( exhibition, ticketGroup.First(), ticketGroup.Count() );
```

I couldn't think of a good reason to make `AddToBasket()` return anything, so I refactored as follows:

```
var pendingOpperations = from ticket in actualTickets
                            group ticket by ticket.ID into ticketGroup
                            select new Action( () => AddToBasket( exhibition, ticketGroup.First(), ticketGroup.Count() ) );

foreach ( var action in pendingOpperations ) action.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement recently, call the action reactively and I write a Do() stream processing function for 1) wrapping the action into a functor with a return value and 2) selecting on the stream.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Do<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
        Action<TSource> action) {

    TSource doSelector(TSource src) {
        action.Invoke(src);
        return src;
    }

    return source
        .Select(it => doSelector(it));
}
```

Please note that this utility function still has to convert the stream into List() to literally call the action for each stream item.

```
var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var sum = 0;
numbers
    .Do(it => { sum += it; })
    .ToList();
```